# Class encapsulation: how to prepare code for adding new classes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, encapsulation

I have the following code:

```
class FooType1 : public FooInterface, public BarInterface1 {}
class FooType2 : public FooInterface, public BarInterface2 {}
class FooType3 : public FooInterface, public BarInterface3 {}

FooInterface service1 = boost::shared_ptr<FooType1>(new FooType1());
FooInterface service2 = boost::shared_ptr<FooType2>(new FooType2());
FooInterface service3 = boost::shared_ptr<FooType3>(new FooType3());

new Host(service1, service2, service3);

Host::Host(boost::shared_ptr<BarInterface1> service1, 
           boost::shared_ptr<BarInterface2> service2,
           boost::shared_ptr<BarInterface3> service3) {
    obj1 = service1;
    obj2 = service2;
    obj3 = service3;
}
```

I need to add `FooType4`, `FooType5`, etc. in a way analogoues to `FooType1` through `FooType3`. In the `Host` constructor I have to assign the proper service to the proper object (1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc.). Given that I know there will be many new services added, how can I properly encapsulate this?

I thought about vector, because in a few places I have to perform some actions on all services so a "for each" loop will be helpful. How I can get the objects from a vector for the `Host` constructor in a reasonable way? Maybe some design pattern?

Comment: Pass in a precreated vector. Include an `AddService` member function. PIck whatever way makes the most sense and use it.

Comment: This smells like a case for composition over inheritance. Think about a factory pattern or something.

Answer (score 1):

You said,

> I need to add `FooType4,`FooType5`, etc. in a way analogoues to`FooType1`through`FooType3`. In the`Host` constructor I have to assign the proper service to the proper object (1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc.). Given that I know there will be many new services added, how can I properly encapsulate this?

Given that, your approach is not the right one. If you haven't read the [Open/Closed Prinicple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), I strongly recommend reading it.

A better approach might be to allow services to be added to a `Host` by clients. This is what I am thinking.

```
class Host
{
   public:
      void addService(std::shared_ptr<FooInterface> service)
      {
         services_.push_back(service);
      }

   private:
      std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FooInterface>> service_;
};
```

And use it as:

```
Host* host = new Host(service1, service2, service3);
host->addService(std::shared_ptr<FooInterface>(new FooType1()));
host->addService(std::shared_ptr<FooInterface>(new FooType2()));
host->addService(std::shared_ptr<FooInterface>(new FooType3()));
```